#   java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getEffectiveSessionTrackingModes()Ljava/util/Set; 

Tags: java, servlets, jboss

i want to have a servlet to process inputs from a standalone java program. how to deploy this servlet in jboss. I put the servlet.class file in WEB-INF/classes and in web.xml i gave the servlet url mapping as ".do". From my Java client program i opened connected to the servlet using a URL object. using localhost:8080/.do. BUT i am getting the folowing error:

```
  ERROR [org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter] An exception or error occurred in the container during the request processing: 
  java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getEffectiveSessionTrackingModes()Ljava/util/Set;
            at
     org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.postParseRequest(CoyoteAdapter.java:567)
            at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877)
            at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:654)
            at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:951)
```

web.xml file contents :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN" "java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">; 
<web-app> 
     <servlet>
         <servlet-name>ReverseServlet</servlet-name> 
         <servlet-class>ReverseServlet</servlet-class> 
     </servlet> 
     <servlet-mapping>
          <servlet-name>ReverseServlet</servlet-name> 
          <url-pattern>/*.do</url-pattern> 
     </servlet-mapping> 
</web-app>
```

Comment: and if possible your servlet code. It seems like method you have mentioned in server is not present or there is some typo error in web.xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE web-app
    PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN"
    "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">

<web-app>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>ReverseServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>ReverseServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping><servlet-name>ReverseServlet</servlet-name>
                      <url-pattern>/*.do</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>

Comment: Servlet code LINK http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/examples/ReverseServlet.java

Comment: Hi, Please remove web.xml contents from 'comments' section. I have added those in your 'question' itself. While adding content, I noticed that there is semi-colon (;) after <!DOCTYPE> element. Remove that semi-colon and re deploy app. Maybe it will work

Comment: I dint get you. Can u please explain in detail. der is no semi colon after doctype.

Comment: Currently your <!DOCTYPE> element is looking as follows : <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN" "java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">;

There is an semi colon at the end of line. You need to remove it.

Answer (score 12):

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.ServletContext.getEffectiveSessionTrackingModes()Ljava/util/Set;

This method is [introduced](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getEffectiveSessionTrackingModes%28%29) in Servlet 3.0. This error can have at least the following causes:

1. Your `web.xml` is not declared conform at least Servlet 3.0.
2. Your servlet container does not support at least Servlet 3.0.
3. You have servlet container specific libraries of an older version in `/WEB-INF/lib`.

To solve this problem,

1. Ensure that your `web.xml` root declaration conforms Servlet 3.0:

   ```xml
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <web-app 
       xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
       version="3.0">

       <!-- Config here. -->

   </web-app>
   ```
2. Ensure that you're deploying to a Servlet 3.0 compatible container. In case of JBoss AS that would be *at least* version 6.0.0.
3. Ensure that you don't have those libraries in `/WEB-INF/lib`. They do not belong there. This is a common beginner's mistake to "solve" compilation errors they faced in their IDE. See also [How do I import the javax.servlet API in my Eclipse project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4076601/how-do-i-import-the-javax-servlet-api-in-my-eclipse-project)

You've declared your `web.xml` conform Servlet 2.2. This is definitely wrong. Fix it accordingly.

Comment: I feel like this is only half the answer. Obviously it's possible to run a Servlet 2.2 app without encountering this exception; it's not as though all sites were perma-broken until Servlet 3.0 was released.

Comment: @ruakh: I'm nowhere telling that this isn't possible. If you're actually unable to run a Servlet 2.2 webapp on a Servlet 3.0 container yourself, then your webapp conflicts point 3 in the answer.

Comment: The OP didn't specify that (s)he was trying to use Servlet 3.0. Your answer even says "You've declared your `web.xml` conform Servlet 2.2. This is definitely wrong", but I don't see any basis for that. The problem is apparently a version mismatch between two things; your answer is about changing the 2.2 stuff to 3.0, but the OP might actually need the 3.0 stuff changed to 2.2.

Comment: @ruakh: the line `<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN" "java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2_2.dtd">` in OP's `web.xml` does that.

Comment: No, you misunderstand me. the "You've declared your `web.xml` conform Servlet 2.2" part is obviously correct; it's the "This is definitely wrong" part that I don't see any basis for.

Comment: (The reason I bring this up is -- I got to this question by Google because of a problem in one of my services. As far as I can tell, it's set up identically to two other services that do work, and all of their `web.xml`-s say 2.x. So I'm trying to figure out what's wrong with this third service. From your answer, I gather that it's that some sort of 3.0+ has snuck in, but your answer is silent about that possibility or how to address it.)